# insert data into table that have one primary key, another foreign key using query

Tags: mysql, database, insert, foreign-keys, primary-key

I wanna know how I can insert new fresh data into Doctor table that have one primary key another foreign key.

For example, I have I added values for person table as below, please show me how it's done on Doctor Table.

```
create table Doctor(
    DoctorID char(6) Primary Key,
    MedicalDegrees varchar(20),
    PersonID int not null REFERENCES Person (PersonID),
    check(DoctorID like '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'));
```

---

```
create table Person(
    PersonID int Primary Key,
    FirstName varchar(15),
    LastName varchar(15),
    StreetAddress varchar(25),
    City varchar(15),
    State varchar(2),
    Zip varchar(5),
    PhoneNumber varchar(10),
    SSN varchar(9) UNIQUE);
```

---

```
insert into person values('1', 'John', 'Smith', '2343 sdf', 'Tacoma', 'WA', 98001, 5268964563, 564657415)
```

Much thanks in advance

Comment: You insert your data just like you did for your Person table, you just need to make sure that the foreign key you're going to use actually exists in Person table.

Comment: I tried many many times but I don't get the right syntax that's why I asked. Thank anyway...

Comment: It is the same syntax, having a primary key with a foreign key doesn't change the syntax, plus, if you tried it many times, can you post one of your tries please?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by How to add data into Doctor table?
Just like you added records to person table, you can add the records to the Doctor table.
Because Doctor table has a reference column to person table you have to insert the record in person table first then into Doctor table and the value of PersonId in Doctor table must exists in Person table.
Please add the query and issues you are facing while inserting data into referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you think that you need a different query for inserting data into a table that has both a primary key and a foreign key, queries doesn't change according to tables design.

Since you already have a query that you posted in your question, we'll use it to insert data into `Doctor` table.

Your query is:

```
insert into person values('1', 'John', 'Smith', '2343 sdf', 'Tacoma', 'WA', 98001, 5268964563, 564657415)
```

According to this query, now you have data in your `Person` table with an `id = 1`. Therefor now you can insert data into `Doctor` table like this:

```
Insert INTO Doctor Values('1','Brain Damage','1')
```

The `1` we used in the foreign key is the one we inserted into the `Person` table.
Note that you won't be able to insert data into `Doctor` table with an invalid `PersonId` that doesn't exist in `Person` table because it is a `Foreign key` and it has to exists.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know how primary key data can be handled without inserting anything (if that's auto_increment).

Comment: If it's auto_increment, you won't have to insert it, it will be inserted by itself.  You can select it normally as well or search by it's criteria